# Passing dynamic request path when calling backends in Ballerina service

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to pass the path of my backend request dynamically. But the path variable is sensitive parameter and hence does not allow me to pass incoming path or any string like, studentInfoEP->get("/student" + studentId);

Any idea how we can do that?

```
endpoint http:Client studentInfoEP {
    url: "http://localhost:9091/studentinfo"
};

@http:ServiceConfig { basePath: "/studentfinder" }
service<http:Service> studentFinder bind listener {


    @http:ResourceConfig {
        methods: ["GET"],
        path: "/{studentId}"
    }
    getStudentById(endpoint client, http:Request req, string studentId) {

        var studentInfoResp = studentInfoEP->get(req.rawPath);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ballerina programs are expected to produce and consume network services and these programs can easily introduce security vulnerabilities such as SQL injection, unvalidated redirect, etc. Therefore, the Ballerina language is designed in a way to make Ballerina programs are secure by design. This language design includes [taint checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taint_checking) and propagation and an integrated authentication & authorization architecture.

The parameters of `get()` are decorated as security-sensitive, therefore the Ballerina compiler will not allow 'untrusted data' to be passed to this function. Untrusted data can come from program arguments, HTTP requests, files, etc. Please refer to "[How to Write Secure Ballerina Programs](https://ballerina.io/learn/how-to-write-secure-ballerina-code/)" to learn more about this topic.

Here, in your example, `req.rawPath` may contain a tainted value, therefore the Ballerina compiler will not allow you to pass this tainted value to a sensitive parameter. You are required to perform explicit data sanitization before passing tainted values to sensitive parameters. There are two ways to do this.

Approach 1:

```
string rawPath = untaint req.rawPath;
var studentInfoResp = studentInfoEP->get(rawPath);
```

Notice the `untaint` keyword here. You can simply mark a tainted value as safe by using the `untaint unary expression`.

Approach 2:

```
string rawPath = sanitizePath(req.rawPath);
var studentInfoResp = studentInfoEP->get(rawPath);
```

This `sanitizePath` function validates the path and returns an untainted value by decorating the return type with the `@untainted` annotation.

```
function sanitizePath(string rawPath) returns @untainted string {
    string value = rawPath;
    // Validate the path value and return
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The path parameter in HTTP Client call is designated as security-sensitive. The compiler generates an error when untrusted data passed into a security-sensitive parameter

"untaint" unary expression can be used to denote that the proceeding value is trusted. But it is essential to do a proper data validation to make sure input does not result in a security threat.

```
var studentInfoResp = studentInfoEP->get("/student" + untaint studentId);
```